# Mediation analysis with 5 Independent variables in R

Tags: r, mediation, mice, lavaan

I am new to the mediation analysis and i am trying to find my way...

So, I have the following dataset:

**X's** : 5 independent variables (D, E, F, G, H), where H is the sum of the other 4 (probably not very wise to be in the analysis, and also the models produces an error whrn i include it, and so i left it out ), continuous

**M's** : 1 mediator (B), continuous

**Y**  :  1 response (I), continuous

**Z**  :  1 covariate (not in the output yet), continuous

I also have some missing values for some of them (around 6-7%).

So, i have first to use MICE to input and then run the mediation analysis. But, as i found out it is not straightforward to combine them, so i used this example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jrbauer/multiple-imputation-mediation-in-r). They use the lavaan package in R.

The output i got, is the following :

[image]

Can somebody please help me interpret this output here ? I am very confused with the several predictors in the model and i don't know how to assess mediation or not...And even if it is appropriate to add all these variables in a model like this..

And finally, if you know something more elegant about the combination of MICE and mediation analysis...

Thanks

Comment: You can try looking into `mediation` package or `medflex` package in R. `Mediation` package is more mature and has more features but has some limits for model type. (Feel free to make this a comment once you see this).

Comment: Thanks @V.Aslanyan ! I was indeed looking at the mediation package..But i am not sure how to apply the 4 predictors, because it "uses only the first" as the warning says...And also, i tried to use mediations  function which is precisely for many datasets (as he case of multiple imputation), but i get an error and i can't figure it out...  {Error in rep(1, nrow(dataarg)) : invalid 'times' argument}

Comment: I am not familiar with any literature concerning multiple independent variables as treatment variable. As for the error, look what it is taking as your `dataarg`, seems like it does not have rows, maybe it requires your dataset to be in a different format.

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately there is not an example somewhere with mice() + mediation() ... And in their documentation they only mention it without an example! Anyway, thanks for you answer!

Comment: Don't know how much this will help you, but at this stage of our research we are looking into developing multiple treatment models and I found this [paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~kbansak/cgi-bin/Bansak_CompCausMed_20180402.pdf). Please let me know if you find anything relevant too. I would greatly appreciate it.